# How can we implement a scan functionality that will scan a w3c Verifiable Credential QR code in React Native

Tags: react-native, w3c, w3c-validation

Unable to find a module that will let me scan a w3c Verifiable Credential QR code for react native.

I have tried to use RNVcamera with vc-js and zbar.wasm in react native; to capture frames and process them through vc-js and zbar.wasm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.